# How to repel pigeons so that they don't loiter behind my windows?

Tags: windows, pest-control

I live in a apartment in a multistory building. Pigeons often sit onto edges of window openings behind my windows and leave excrements which is rather annoying.

Is there some simple, preferably without violence, way to repel pigeons off my windows?

Comment: For some reason, the title reminded me of [The Farside](http://static.tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pub/images/Beware_the_pigeons_The_Far_Side_3012.jpg).

Answer (score 4):

Many buildings in my area have the same problem. I have seen many clever items, but the one that seems to work well is a strip of plastic with stainless nails extending up from under the plastic sill covers. These are constructed with strips of acrylic plexeglass cut to fit over the exterior window sill, then drilled every few inches all over with Stainless 3 inch nails protruding up from under the strips.   The birds will not land on the sharp points.

Answer (score 1):

Get a cat as a pet..
They will avoid your house for sure..
and you will get a good companion too...what say

Comment: Remember to check with OSHA to see what safety harnesses a cat would require for working outside at heights. In my experience it's very difficult to get cats into a full fall arrest rig.

Comment: @mgb: Why did you (try to) put a cat into a full fall arrest rig?

Comment: Cats don't need a harness - they always land on their feet! Just like toast always lands butter side down. Just don't put buttered toast on the harness. A girl in my high school went all Mythbusters on it and dropped her cat out of her tree house with buttered toast taped to its back. The toast won. :/

Comment: @Tester101. Cats have a very poor attitude to workplace safety - they think they have 9 lives or something

Comment: you guys are really giving Vral a workover on his first attempt.  lolololololol   love it!

Comment: While the harness is an option, I've had better luck with feline safety chutes. They increase their lives by at least 3.

Answer (score 0):

Spary bottle filled with fairly diluted ammonia. Open the window and spray them whenever they show up. They don't stay away permanently, but they really don't like it. It's not as effective as a permanent hardware solution like the spike strips, but you don't need to work on the exterior of your place either.

Answer (score 0):

I say go the urban food route. Get some super itty bitty bear traps and bait them with birdseed. SQUAB FOR DINNER!